# fill circle with change color after few second

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, quartz-graphics

[image]

I am implementing a custom progress bar using a timer and the Quartz2d draw circle/fill circle functions. Basically, I am using `CGContextAddLines,CGContextAddArc,CGContextDrawPath` methods but with limited success.

My Progress bar is implemented as a circle with a black background. Activity in the progress bar is implemented as an internal, incrementing segment of purple color. The segment is drawn in increments from -90 degrees (as shown in the image) and finishing at 360 degree. Ten seconds after the progress activity completes I am trying to change the fill color of the circle back to black.

My problem is that even though I can completely fill the color with purple, I am having trouble resetting the black background of the circle after 10 seconds. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code? Also, please check the edits to your question above to make sure they make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a method to reset the circle and then call it performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: and set afterDelay to 10 seconds?